# Blessing Shehechyanu long before eating in second evening of Rosh Hashana

Tags: halacha, blessing, yom-tov, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shehecheyanu

Usually, we bless Shehechyanu very close to eating a new fruit. As far as I remember, there are 2 opinions: one to bless before the blessing on the fruit itself, while the other opinion claims that you bless Shehechyanu after the blessing of the fruit, right before eating. In the second evening of Rosh Hashana, we bless Shehechyanu in the Kiddush, long before eating the new fruit. Moreover, there are many blessings and distractions between them such as Birkat Hamotizi, Netilat Yadaim etc. Why shouldn't we repeat the Shehechyanu right before eating the fruit? How is the Kiddush Shehechyanu blessing is applicable in advance?

Comment: On Purim, we recite a Shehechyanu "on" the other mitzvos of the day when we read megilla earlier in the morning. The "pause" doesn't seem to be an obstacle there.

Comment: Some (myself included) eat the new fruit immediately after kiddush, before washing for hamotzi

Comment: @rosends Not a great proof since those mitzvot don't actually halachically need a shehechiyanu https://judaism.codidact.com/posts/280925/280936#answer-280936

Answer (score 4):

See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 225:3. One makes *shehecheyanu* upon *seeing* a new fruit (although customarily this blessing is deferred until eating of the fruit).

Thus, on the second night of Rosh HaShanah, Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 600:2 recommends having a new fruit in front of you while reciting *kiddush*. Thus, as far as I understand, the *shehecheyanu* of *kiddush* also applies to seeing the new fruit on the table.

(Similarly, Mishnah Berurah 600:4 recommends that a woman who has the custom to recite *shehecheyanu* at candle lighting should have a new fruit in front of her while lighting on the second night of Rosh HaShanah. Again, the *shehecheyanu* will apply to seeing the new fruit in front of her, although she won’t eat it until later.)

Comment: To be more explicit, while we usually delay saying shehechiyanu to just before eating, that isn't really necessary and 'we' don't generally bother with it on the second night of Rosh Hashana for practical reasons. (I've always wanted to have fresh grape juice for kiddush that night!)